# Django internal redirect/url rewriting

Tags: django, url

The situation is the following:

I have the url `/app/categories/` that supports filtering by query arguments

- `/app/categories/` returns all categories
- `/app/categories/?project=1` returns all categories for the project with ID 1.

I want to also have an URL `/app/projects/1/categories` that will return the same result as `/app/categories/?project=1` but without having to rewrite the view. Is it possible to make some kind of internal redirect or url rewriting such that when requesting `/app/projects/1/categories` the result will be the same as calling `/app/categories/?project=1`, but without redirecting? (in the future I might need to make the same thing for unsafe methods)

Answer (score 2):

Make a common function that takes project id as argument and returns the categories object.

```
def get_categories(pk):
  categories = Category.objects.filter(project=pk)
  return categories
```

To add your url add this in `urls.py`,

```
url(r'^projects/(?P<pk>\d+)/categories/$', views.category_view,name="yourname"),
```

your views.py should look like this,

```
 # /app/categories/?project=1
 def category_view(request):
    get_categories = get_categories(request.GET.get('project_id'))
    # your logic

 # /app/projects/1/categories
 def other_category_view(request,pk):
    get_categories = get_categories(pk)
    # your logic
```